# Spread Operator add element with key in array

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if i can add an element in my array with a specific key with Spread Operator.

```
let foo = ['a','b','c'];
foo = [...foo,'d'];
```

In this case `foo[3]` would be `d`. But can i add `d` with a custon key in my `foo` array and then access with something like: `foo['customKey']`?

Comment: Why don't you use object rather than array?

Comment: _But can i add d with a custon key in my foo array and then access with something like: foo['customKey']_ no you can't. Elements in an array are accessed by the index.

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) instead of spreading an array, because this allows only to take [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Built-in_iterables) items for the new array.

```js
let foo = ['a','b','c'];

foo = Object.assign([], [...foo], { customKey: 'd' });

console.log(foo);
console.log(foo.customKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are objects in JavaScript therefore they can have properties:

```js
let foo = ['a','b','c'];
foo['customKey'] = 'd';
//Note using a for-in not for-of to iterate over enumerable & string properties
for (i in foo){
  console.log("The type of index is also a string: ", typeof i, i);
}
```

In fact when you access a array element using a number index, it is coerced into a string.

But with your use case, you should consider using an object:

```js
let foo = {'foo' : ['a' , 'b','c']};
foo['customKey'] = 'd';
//Note using a for-in not for-of to iterate over enumerable & string properties
for (i in foo){
  console.log(foo[i]);
}

//Using object destructing
const d = {'anotherKey': 'e'};
const newFoo = {...foo, ...d};
console.log(newFoo);
```